# What is the Visual C runtime?

Tags: visual-c++, dll, runtime

I just wanted to know what is inside the Visual C ++ runtime DLLs? What code? Which functions? Just curious about that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Is contains standard functions, like prinft, exit etc.

You can find the source code for the library in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\crt\src"  (This is Visual Studio 2008)

The basic dll for Visual Studio 2008 is is **msvcrt90.dll**

See also this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx)

Comment: If that's is true why I do not need to deploy a C runtime when I compile an application that uses printf with gcc for example?

Answer (score 1):

The runtime contains code, that is common to/needed in all C++ programs ('think default libraries') and generaly links your code to the OS and it's API.

Code to initialise the app, set up I/O, minimal error reporting/logging, memory management etc ..